# How to replace data with Beautifull Soup

Tags: html, replace

I have some html with next data:

```html
<body>

<p>Select
<select></select>
</p>

</body>
```

I have to peplase  with 
Volvo

Help me please!

Comment: what is the question here? refer https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

[Here is documentation for select tag in Russian](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

[In english](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

```html
<body>

<p>Select
<select name="car">
  <option id="1">Volvo</option>
  <option id="2">Lada</option>
  <option id="3">Volga</option>
</select>
</p>

</body>
```

Comment: sorry, i have mistake. I have to replace <select></select> with <select><option value="volvo">Volvo</option></select>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>

<p>Select
    <select>
       <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    </select>
</p>

</body>
```

There you go!

Comment: sorry, i have mistake. I have to parse html with soup then insert into  <select></select>  tag  an <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> tag

Comment: You should tag python as well.